# Symfony2 Doctrine2 orphanRemoval doesn't work when using own postLoad event listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Service (product), which has many Inventories. When user logs in, let's say he is assigned to only one Location. That is why I have to filter array collection, so the user can not edit inventories from other locations. Number of inventories is usually small. I have a ServiceType form which has a collection type, where inventories can be edited, added and removed.

The problem is.. I have set up an entity listener for only the Service entity, and after loading it from the database, the postLoad method is executed, which saves the filtered inventories to the array collection. On the form type, I see only the filtered ones, as expected, also editing works, and when I add a new item to the collection, it also works. When I hit the delete button on collection item, and submit the form, the removeInventory() method is called and item is removed from collection. But then when I persist Service, doctrine does not generate DELETE query and 'deleted' inventories are not deleted from the database. When I visit the form again, the items are still on the list. However, everything (also delete) works, if I do not use postLoad method.

Commenting this line

```
$service->setInventory($inventory->matching($criteria));
```

fixes the not deleting problem, but ofcourse I get all items, not only filtered ones.

Inventory mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Inventory" table="inventory">

    <indexes>
      <index name="fk_inventory_location1_idx" columns="location_id"/>
      <index name="fk_inventory_service1_idx" columns="service_id"/>
    </indexes>

    <entity-listeners>
      <entity-listener class="Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Listener\InventoryListener">
          <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="prePersistHandler"/>
      </entity-listener>
    </entity-listeners>

    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>

    <field name="quantity"  type="integer"  column="quantity"   nullable="false"/>
    <field name="stock"     type="integer"  column="stock"      nullable="false"/>

    <many-to-one field="service" target-entity="Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Service" inversed-by="inventory">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="service_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>

    <many-to-one field="location" target-entity="Service\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Location" inversed-by="inventory">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="location_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>

  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

And Service mapping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Service" table="service">

    <indexes>
      <index name="fk_service_account1_idx" columns="account_id"/>
    </indexes>

    <entity-listeners>
      <entity-listener class="Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Listener\ServiceListener">
          <lifecycle-callback type="postLoad" method="postLoadHandler"/>
      </entity-listener>
    </entity-listeners>

    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>

    <field name="name"          type="string"   column="name"           length="255"                nullable="false"/>
    <field name="description"   type="text"     column="description"                                nullable="true"/>
    <field name="stockable"     type="boolean"  column="stockable"                                  nullable="false"/>

    <field name="value"         type="decimal"  column="value"          precision="15"  scale="4"   nullable="false"/>
    <field name="tax"           type="decimal"  column="tax"            precision="5"   scale="2"   nullable="false"/>
    <field name="unit"          type="string"   column="unit"           length="63"                 nullable="false"/>

    <one-to-many target-entity="Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Inventory" mapped-by="service" field="inventory" fetch="LAZY" orphan-removal="true">
      <cascade>
          <cascade-persist/>
          <cascade-remove/>
      </cascade>
    </one-to-many>

    <one-to-many target-entity="Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Price" mapped-by="service" field="priceList" fetch="LAZY" orphan-removal="true">
      <cascade>
          <cascade-persist/>
          <cascade-remove/>
      </cascade>
    </one-to-many>

    <many-to-one field="account" target-entity="Service\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Account">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="account_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>

  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Service entity listener:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: tomaz
 * Date: 06/05/14
 * Time: 15:33
 */

namespace Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Listener;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

use Service\Bundle\RepairBundle\Entity\Service;
use Service\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

class ServiceListener
{
    protected $container;

    /** Doctrine entity listeners should have container injection, because of lazy loading other services, to avoid circular references
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function postLoadHandler(Service $service, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        if($service instanceof Service) # Should always be true
        {
            $inventory = $service->getInventory();

            if($this->getUser() instanceof User)
            {
                $criteria = Criteria::create()
                    ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('location', $this->getUser()->getPrimaryLocation()))
                    ->orderBy(array('timeInsert' => Criteria::ASC));

                $service->setInventory($inventory->matching($criteria));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return User|null
     */
    private function getUser()
    {
        return $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in this line:

$service->setInventory($inventory->matching($criteria));

If I remove it, removing works, but filter doesn't.

Comment: I rewrote the code and made a entity listener instead, and the problem is still there. Adding new items work, delete still does nothing.

Comment: More info: Doctrine does UPDATE statement for edited items or INSERT for new ITEMS, but does not do an UPDATE/DELETE from items I remove from collection.

Comment: Can you please explain your problem better. Like what you want to achieve, your mapping and orphan etc...